# What is this not saving the term

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the term to favorites via a short code. However when I add the short code [add_term term_id=840"] (for example..where term id=840 is a one particular term). It's not adding to my list of favorited terms? I don't know why...

```
function add_termid( $atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
    'term_id' => 'term_id', 
    ), $atts
    );
    }
    function store()
    {
        global $userdata;
        $favorites_to_store = array();
        foreach($this->favorites as $favorite) 
        {
            $favorites_to_store[] = array('term_id' => $favorite['term_id'],                          'taxonomy' => $favorite['taxonomy']);
        }
        if(version_compare(get_bloginfo('version'), '3.0', '<')) update_usermeta($userdata->ID, 'wp_favorites', $favorites_to_store);
        else update_user_meta($userdata->ID, 'wp_favorites', $favorites_to_store); 
    }
add_shortcode ('add_term', 'add_termid');
```